# Undelete a deleted question?

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, undelete

I asked my first question, about making Jini servers undiscoverable, on Stack Overflow last night, then deleted it because I thought I should do some more research first.

I guess I shouldn't have been so hasty. Can I undelete it? I don't have the URL, and it doesn't appear in the Questions part of my profile.

Comment: Is this your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421730/exclusive-use-of-a-jini-server-during-long-running-call

Comment: @Dennis He can't see it anyway. The title is "Exclusive use of a Jini server during long-running call". Is that the one you wish to undelete?

Comment: The question looks off-topic anyways, to be honest. It looks like it *might* fit over on Programmers.

Answer (score 6):

I've undeleted it for you. Enjoy.

As mentioned in the comments, the question does look a bit off-topic for Stack Overflow. You may want to try it on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) instead. It's a site that takes the most subjective/best-practice type questions like yours.

Comment: Or you can just migrate it there - as a former Programmers.SE Mod. :)

Comment: @Mysticial I can, but I'd rather let the community/Matthew take over here. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear: i have deleted my answer but it visible to me.your comment "This actually isn't going to work - unless the OP has 10,000 reputation on SO, he can't see his question." seem not correct.Or it does not apply on answer

Comment: @TofeeqAhmad: You can always see your own deleted answers if you revisit the question (they're not listed under your account though). However, you can only see a deleted question until you leave the page.

Comment: @TofeeqAhmad It's different for answers. Your deleted answer is visible to you and users with 10,000 reputation (plus moderators, obviously).

Comment: ok thank you @AnnaLear to make me correct.But i feel i can not make reputation on meta as its very hard.Every time my point proved wrong.Please suggest me some question on how to increase reputation on meta

Comment: @TofeeqAhmad You could start by reading the [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) and all linked material to it. It's a lot to read, but you'll learn a lot about how Stack Exchange works and you can then spread the knowledge on Meta and harvest the sweet rep ;)

Comment: Eh... the question got closed as Off Topic rather than migrated. Programmers doesn't have the [tag:jini] tag.

Comment: @mysticial There was no guarantee the question would be migrated, Anna just undeleted it.

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast Yeah I know. I was hoping for it to get migrated and 3 of the first 4 votes were for migration. (I'm not sure about the 5th vote though.) But since the tag doesn't exist on programmers it can't be migrated. Unless it's retagged and reopened/reclosed. Or if a mod steps in.

Comment: @Mysticial Well I was about to tell you to ask around on Programmers chat to see if the community wants the question (I'm a Programmers mod, but I don't know anything about Jini), when I noticed Anna migrated it. Oh well, Anna knows best...

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast It seems reasonable. I hope I'm not wrong.

Comment: @AnnaLear From the parts of it I understand, it seems like a perfect fit. But don't know enough about Jini to know if it's a horribly trivial or outlandishly wrong question. Oh, well, we'll find out soon enough ;)